# Setting git remote fetch and push url in a single command

Tags: git

The command

`$ git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myorg/myrepo.git`

will only set the `fetch` URL, not the `push` URL:

```
$ git push origin
remote: Too many invalid password attempts. Try logging in through the website with your password.
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/myorg/myrepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myorg/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin  https://bitbucket.org/myorg/myrepo.git (push)
```

I have to set the `push` URL separately

```
$ git remote set-url --push origin git@bitbucket.org:myorg/myrepo.git
```

### Question

I recall having been able to set both `push` and `fetch` URL in a single command.

1. Was there a change in `git` so that `git remote set-url` will only change the `fetch` URL by default?
2. Is there a way to set both URL in a single command?

Comment: I worked with different versions of git, no once time meet such behaviour. It always add or set both url.

Answer (score 3):

After you've used `git remote set-url --push` there are 2 URLs for a remote (for fetching and pushing) and `git remote set-url` only changes the fetch URL. To make `git remote set-url` change both URLs just remove `pushurl` from that remote.

Answer (score 1):

By default it always add or set both url (`fetch` and `push`).

> Was there a change in git so that git remote set-url will only change the fetch URL by default?

When you at least once to do change remote with key `--path` it will update it separately: `fetch` with no key `--path`, and `path` with key `--path`

> Is there a way to set both URL in a single command?

- Remove your url by name.
- Add it again with no `--push` key
  It will now set both url (push and fetch) for that remote.

Comment: -1: Removing the remote also prunes your remote tracking branches. This is destructive and goes beyond updating the URLs themselves.

Comment: This is the answer to the question of older versions of git (for example, 2.11 and maybe newer). Your clarification is just an additional notice for the answer, and this is not a reason to devote until the oldest version is available.